# How to make this SQL query with Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm null in SQL.

I have two tables `works` and `types`.

`works` contain a foreign_key `type_id` which references a work type (in my DB, this is the ID of a type).

`type` contain an `ID`, `name` and `slug`.

I would like to get all works from a particular type. Example: Get all works with the type `website` (website is the slug).

My relation for my model Work

```
public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Type');
}
```

My relation for my model Type

```
public function works()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Work');
}
```

I tried this but it's totaly wrong

`Work::with('types')->where('slug', $request->get('type'));`

Thank you !

Comment: `Type::with('works')->where('slug', $variable)->first();`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy -- correct, then to get all of the works, use `Type::with('works')->where('slug', $request->get('type'))->first()->works;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your relationship is defined as `type` and you're loading `types`.

```
$works = Work::whereHas('type', function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('slug', $request->get('type'));
})->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand your request and it work